# how to get the name of the activity dynamically in ADF

Tags: azure-databricks, azure-data-factory

I have a pipeline which takes the name of all stages and use it in the notebook,
how to fetch the name of each stage dynamically in ADF and use it?
how to achieve this case?

Comment: Can you please provide an example of your requirement?

Comment: i wanted to trigger an email if any stage fails in my Pipeline and also log the details into a delta table. for that i was planning to connect the notebook which fetches the stage name, error details dynamically from that failed stage and send an email. this notebook will be connected to all stages.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, **it is not possible in ADF to get the activity name dynamically**. But, as you want the failed activity name, we can get the name from the error itself (in this case).

Please follow the demonstration below:

First, treat **your main pipeline as a child pipeline** and execute it using a parent pipeline and use the parent pipeline to get the activity name and error in the child pipeline.

This is my sample child pipline (main pipeline). In this, to create an error I gave wrong source file path in the copy activity named as **My Copy Data**.

[image]

Use Set Variable to store the error and activity name by which the error was generated after the execute pipeline activity in the parent pipeline.

`@activity('Execute Pipeline1').error.message` this will give you error like `Operation on target activity failed`. By using this we can get name of the activity in next variable.

**Set variable activity for Error:**

[image]

**Set Variable for activity name:**

Use this expression to get activity name.

```
@substring(variables('error'),  add(indexOf(variables('error'),'target'),7),  sub(indexOf(variables('error'),'failed'),add(indexOf(variables('error'),'target'),7)))
```

[image]

**Databricks Notebook activity:**


create a databricks notebook activity and pass these variables as parameters to it and store it in the delta table.


[image]

**Code in databricks notebook:**

```
activity_name=dbutils.widgets.get("activity_name")
error=dbutils.widgets.get("error")

#Create a delta table before this and append these values on delta table for 
every failure

print(activity_name)
print(error)
```

**Databricks Job after execution:**

[image]

You can get mail by using a logic app after Notebook activity and pass the activity name and error message to it using web activity.

First create a logic app for mail by following this [Official Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-send-email).

Then, give the URL of logic app in web activity and body like below.

```
{

"message" : "The failed activity in your pipeline is @{variables('activityname')}

and This is the error message @{variables('error')}.",

"dataFactoryName" : "@{pipeline().DataFactory}",

"pipelineName" : "@{pipeline().Pipeline}",

"receiver" : "@{pipeline().parameters.reciever}"

}
```

[image]

Now you can get the mail for every failure of your child pipeline.